# Corrwith within a single df

Tags: python, pandas

everyone. I'm trying to do a correlation row-wise, so I can find out how two rows compare with one another. I'm trying to look up corrwith but everything I find shows only two dfs interacting and the info I'm working with works differently. Here's some sample data.

```
cols = ['Name', 'Math', 'Science', 'English', "History"]
data = [['Tom', 100, 93, 95, 92], ['Nick', 89, 75, 82, 57], ['Julie', 99, 89, 76, 88], ['Sarah', 79, 78, 94, 88]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
df
```

The output is this:
[image]

What I'm hoping to get is something where I can find the correlation between Tom, Nick, Julie, Sarah in a correlation matrix

I suppose the output I was expecting would be something that would give me the coefficient in a list format or a table below (excuse my Microsoft Word table):
[image]

I'm also open to other ideas that compare how close two students/row are on a series of other subjects/columns. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) after a bit of reshaping (Name as index and [transposed](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) DataFrame):

```
df.set_index('Name').T.corr(method='pearson')
```

Output:

```
Name        Tom      Nick     Julie     Sarah
Name                                         
Tom    1.000000  0.844956  0.527161 -0.306789
Nick   0.844956  1.000000  0.180286 -0.235935
Julie  0.527161  0.180286  1.000000 -0.839516
Sarah -0.306789 -0.235935 -0.839516  1.000000
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Out of curiosity, what does the T refer to?

Comment: This is the transpose to swap index and columns. I added a link to the doc